# autopy gives a ValueError when taking a screenshot

Tags: python, python-3.x, autopy

I'm trying to take an image of a small section on my screen using autopy and for some reason I'm getting an error. For reference, I am running on a 1920x1080 display. Here's the code:

```
box = ((995, 5), (995 + 212, 5 + 72))
autopy.bitmap.capture_screen(box)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The Image's dimensions are either too small or too large
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function

`autopy.bitmap.capture_screen`

takes the top left point in the first tuple and then in the next tuple takes the width and the height. So, to fix your problem, simply use

```
box = ((995, 5), (212, 72))
autopy.bitmap.capture_screen(box)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought the second tuple was the bottom right corner

Comment: No problem :). I thought so too and the documentation is not helpful as well. Figured it out by testing it myself for some time.